# Regular expressions in R to erase all characters after the first space?

Tags: regex, r

I have data in R that can look like this:

```
USDZAR Curncy
R157 Govt
SPX Index
```

In other words, one word, in this case a Bloomberg security identifier, followed by another word, which is the security class, separated by a space. I want to strip out the class and the space to get to:

```
USDZAR
R157
SPX
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this in R? Is it regular expressions or must I do something as I would in MS Excel using the mid and find commands? eg in Excel I would say:

```
=MID(@REF, 1, FIND(" ", @REF, 1)-1)
```

which means return a substring starting at character 1, and ending at the character number of the first space (less 1 to erase the actual space).

Do I need to do something similar in R (in which case, what is the equivalent), or can regular expressions help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1)** Try this where the regular expression matches a space followed by any sequence of characters and `sub` replaces that with a string having zero characters:

```
x <- c("USDZAR Curncy", "R157 Govt", "SPX Index")
sub(" .*", "", x)
## [1] "USDZAR" "R157"   "SPX"
```

**2)** An alternative if you wanted the two words in separate columns in a data frame is as follows.  Here `as.is = TRUE` makes the columns be character rather than factor.

```
read.table(text = x, as.is = TRUE)
##       V1     V2
## 1 USDZAR Curncy
## 2   R157   Govt
## 3    SPX  Index
```

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy with `stringr`:

```
x <- c("USDZAR Curncy", "R157 Govt", "SPX Index")

library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(x, " ", n = 2)[, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me, in that regexp's will always remain an inscrutable, frustrating mystery, this clunkier solution also exists:

```
x <- c("USDZAR Curncy", "R157 Govt", "SPX Index")
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x," ",fixed=TRUE),"[",1))
```

The fixed=TRUE isn't strictly necessary, just pointing out that you can do this (simple case) w/out really knowing the first thing about regexp's.

Edited to reflect @Wojciech's comment.

Comment: haha yes - thank joran. Clunk style is what I'm used to in Excel hence I was wondering if I should (finally) learn regexs.

Comment: anonymous function is not necessary here, so you can simplify to unlist(lapply(strsplit(x," ",fixed=TRUE),"[",1)).

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be to search for:

```
\x20.*
```

and replace with an empty string.

If you want to know whether it's faster, just time it.

Comment: Thanks, right so I'm typing: > grep("\x20.*", "R157 Govt") and I'm getting back: [1] 1 , ie the value 1. Where do I go from there?

Comment: The problem with that use was that you failed to understand that the backslash is special in regex and therefore needs to be "escaped" itself. And it needs to have TWO baackslashes before it when in the pattern argument. Try:  `sub("\\\x20.*", "", "R157 Govt")`